# NEXTJS: getServerSideProps not working into components

Tags: next.js

> Below is the code located at "Pages/home.js". // localhost:3000/home

```js
    import axios from 'axios';
    import Section1 from '../components/home-sections/section-1';
    
    const Homepage = ({ show }) => {
        const Html = JSON.parse(show.response.DesktopHTML);
        const renderSection = () => {
            return Html.map((itemData,index)=>{
                return(<div key={index}>{itemData.DisplayName}</div>)
            })
        }
    
        return(
            <div>
                { renderSection()}
                <Section1 />
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export const getServerSideProps = async ({ query }) => {
     
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          `https://api.example.com/getHomeSection?title=Section 1`
        );
        
        return {
          props: {
            show: response.data,
          },
        };
      } catch (error) {
        return {
          props: {
            error: error.error,
          },
        };
      }
    };
    
    export default Homepage;
```

Now same code I added into section-1.js and this file is located to "`components/home-sections/section-1.js`"

Now `getServerSideProps` is working fine in home.js, but in section-1.js it is not working.

```
Error: TypeError: show is undefined in section-1.js
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You cannot use `getServerSideProps` in non-page components. You can either pass the prop from `Home` to `HomeSection` or create a context so the value can be available globally from the component tree

> getServerSideProps can only be exported from a page. You can’t export
> it from non-page files.

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#only-allowed-in-a-page-2

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66945555/next-js-using-getserversideprops-how-do-i-pass-props-from-page-to-components) is someone that shows how pass a prop to a component

Answer (score 15):

`getServerSideProps` can only be exported from Page components. It will not be run on components imported into a page.

However, you could export a function from the component that returns the props, and call that function from the page's `getServerSideProps` function.

1. Create a `getServerSideProps` function on the component.

   ```
   // @components/MyComponent.tsx
   import { GetServerSidePropsContext } from 'next';

   function MyComponent(props: IMyComponentProps) {
       return (<div>MyComponent</div>;)
   }

   MyComponent.getServerSideProps = async (context: GetServerSidePropsContext): Promise<{ props: IMyComponentProps }> => {
       return { props: { ... } };
   }

   export default MyComponent;
   ```
2. In your page's `getServerSideProps` function, call the component's `getServerSideProps` function and merge the props from the component with the props from the page.

   ```
   // mypage.tsx
   import MyComponent from '@components/MyComponent';

   const Page: NextPageWithLayout = (props: IIndexPageProps) => {
       return <MyComponent />;
   }

   export async function getServerSideProps(context: GetServerSidePropsContext): Promise<{ props: IIndexPageProps }> {
       let componentServerSideProps = await MyComponent.getServerSideProps(context);
       let otherServerSideProps = { props: { ... } };

       return {
           props: {
               ...componentServerSideProps.props,
               ...otherServerSideProps.props
           }
       };
   }
   ```

Answer (score 5):

getServerSideProps won't work in components
it needs to be implemented on a page only
and if you are using the next.js-13 app directory, it won't work there as well, you need to use the pages directory

in the app directory, you just need to write `use client` in the first line for client components and leave it empty for server components

Answer (score 4):

Using the latest Next.js version (13)

Data fetching is now done in a different way.

Reference: [Data Fetching](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching). See also, [Migrating From Pages to App](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration)

Answer (score 1):

You gotta use generateStaticParams() from Next.js v13. Here's the reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-static-params