# How to implement Server Sider Rendering (SSR) for a NextJS component?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to implement Server Sider Rending SSR for a NextJS Typescript component. It's possible to do SSR for a page using getServerSideProps but not found any way for non page child components. It works fine under page folder but no luck outside of page components.

Say I have created a component with API under components folder, here getServerSideProps is not working and even SSR also not working. and can't see the content in page view source DOM.

**/components/user.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import {useEffect,useState} from 'react';

interface User {
    id:number;
    name: string;
    username: string;
    email:string;
  }
  
const Users = () => {
  const [data,setData]= useState([])
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then((result)=>{
      result.json().then((resp)=>{
        setData(resp);
      })
    })
  },[])
  console.log(data)
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {data.map((data: User)=>
                <li key={data.id}>
                    <h2>{data.name}</h2>
                    <h3>{data.username}</h3>
                    <h4>{data.email}</h4>
                </li>
                )}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Users
```

**/pages/user.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Users from "../components/Users";

function user() {
  return (
    <section>
      <h1>User - Component</h1>      
      <main>
        <Users />
      </main>   
       
    </section>
  );
};

export default user;
```

Can you please help how to implement SSR for components which located out side of pages folder?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NEXTJS: getServerSideProps not working into components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64136025/nextjs-getserversideprops-not-working-into-components)

Answer (score 0):

As it notes in the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#:%7E:text=getServerSideProps%20can%20only%20be%20exported%20from%20a%20page.%20You%20can%E2%80%99t%20export%20it%20from%20non%2Dpage%20files.)

> getServerSideProps can only be exported from a page. You can’t export it from non-page files.

This rules out `getServerSideProps`, now for the ask itself

Two options

1. setup a corresponding `pages/component` page
2. Setup a custom server and use the following in `next.config.js` - This allows routing to be on you without using the `pages` as the only place things get served from.

```
module.exports = {
  useFileSystemPublicRoutes: false,
}
```