# How to to use context.query with getServerSideProps()? | NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm facing an issue with my `getServerSideProps()` on my NextJS app.

Basically I'm passing data for an nft collection (name, description, address etc.) manually from an internal json to the url of the collection clicked. When a user click the collection the **dynamic mint page render** with the data of the `router.query`.

I've successfully done it within the Mint page component into a `useEffect` with `router.query`. But when I've tried to make it with
`getServerSideProps()` for SSR, nothing return from the `context.query` (the function below)

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const mint = context.query;
  return { props: { mint } };
}
```

This is the MintSection component below the `getServerSideProps()`

```
function MintSection({ mint }) {
  console.log(mint);

  other code
  ...

}
```

Comment: Is `MintSection` a page component? Keep in mind that `getServerSideProps` only runs in page component, it won't work in regular components. See [NEXTJS: getServerSideProps not working into components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64136025/nextjs-getserversideprops-not-working-into-components).

Answer (score 0):

Use destructuring.

```
const {mint} = context.query;
```